# Transfer array from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have a test.txt file that has two columns of data (x's and y's), eg:

```
#test.txt
1 23
2 234
4 52
43 5
3 35
```

And a python program that reads in these values and stores them in x and y as so:

```
#test.py
# Read the file.
f = open('test.txt', 'r')

# read the whole file into a single variable, which is a list of every  row of the file.
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

# initialize some variable to be lists:
x = []
y = []

# scan the rows of the file stored in lines, and put the values into some variables:
for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    x.append(float(p[0]))
    y.append(float(p[1]))
```

I want to take these values stored in x and y and transfer them to two similar arrays in a javascript program to display them as a graph. How can I transfer between python and javascript?

Comment: Either store the values in a database and use a server side language or invoke a webpage from python and pass it as a parameter(either using `GET` or structured using json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is slightly vague. There are two possible ways your question can be interpreted, here are the corresponding answers:

1. Your python code needs to transfer them to some javascript running in the browser/node.js application. In order to do this, the Python half of your application would need to either store the data in a database and expose the data via some sort of API, which the javascript half could consume. To go a little fancier, you could set up a connection between the two web servers (e.g. socket.io) and have the Python half send the arrays over the connection as they're created.
2. This is what I believe you're trying to do based on the code you've posted: Preprocess some data in Python, and then pass it over to some other javascript piece of the puzzle where there's no real-time aspect to it.

   In this case, you could simply write the arrays to JSON, and parse that in Javascript. To write to a file, you could do:

   ```
   import json
   data = {'x': x, 'y': y}
   # To write to a file:
   with open("output.json", "w") as f:
       json.dump(data, f)

   # To print out the JSON string (which you could then hardcode into the JS)
   json.dumps(data)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear as to why you want to transfer this, but you can write it out into a js file simply by formatting the list into `var someList = [[x1,y1], [x2,y2]]`.

Would be easier to build the string up withing `from line in lines` but in case you do have actual need of maintaining separate x and y lists

```
zippedList = list(list(zipped) for zipped in zip(xList,yList))
print('var someList = {};'.format(zippedList))
```

which gives you

> var someList = [[1, 23], [2, 234], [4, 52], [43, 5], [3, 35]];

Write this out to a js file as needed or append to an existing html as

```
with open('index.html','a') as f:
    f.write('<script> var transferredList={}; </script>'.format(zippedList))
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't put the arrays stored in variables x and y, but you can do it if you know at least a bit of JavaScript.

```
var Request=new XMLHttpRequest();//request object
Request.open("GET","test.txt",true);
/*
 * Open request;
 * Take 2 arguments, but third is optional (async).
 * If you want async, then set onreadystatechange instead of onload event
*/
Request.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.status==400){//status is okay
        var Lines=this.responseText.split("\n");
        alert(Lines[0])//will alert the first line
    }
    /*
     * this.status>=500 are request issues or user network delay
     * this.status=404 means file not found
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you mention "display" together with `JavaScript`, I somewhat assume that your goal is to have `JavaScript` in a web browser displaying the data that your `python` script reads from the file in the backend. Transferring from backend `python` to frontend `JavaScript` is a piece of cake, because both languages "speak" JSON.

In the backend, you will do something like

```
import json
response = json.dumps(response_object)
```

and in the frontend, you can right away use

```
var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
```

It is also quite clear how the frontend will call the backend, namely using `ajax`, usually wrapped in a handy library like `jQuery`.

The field opens, when it comes to making your `python` script run in a web server. A good starting point for this would be [the Python How-To](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html) for using `python` in the web. You will have to consult with your web hosting service, too, because most hosters have clear guidance whether they admit `CGI`or, for example `FastCGI`. Once this is clear, maybe you want to take a look at the `Flask` micro-framework or something similar, which are offering many services you will need right out-of-the-box.

I have mentioned all the buzzwords here to enable your own investigation ;)